# Entity Framework Code First Renaming Columns/Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an `Employee` table that links employees to their contact info. I have it set up like so:

```
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HomePhoneId")]
    public virtual PhoneNumber HomePhone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WorkPhoneId")]
    public virtual PhoneNumber WorkPhone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CellPhoneId")]
    public virtual PhoneNumber CellPhone { get; set; }
```

When I try to load employees from the database, however, it automatically renames the columns, completely overriding the attributes:

```
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber_Id'.

Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber_Id1'.

Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber_Id2'.

Invalid column name 'Address_Id'.
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: What does the rest of your Employee model look like?  Do you have properties for the foreign key ids?  AddressId, HomePhoneId, etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @mcbowes, it is hard to tell without seeing the rest of your Employee class, but most likely you are missing the following in your class:

```
public int AddressId { get; set; }

public int HomePhoneId { get; set; }

public int WorkPhoneId { get; set; }

public int CellPhoneId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDs were all properly specified for each navigation property. It seems the problem had to do with the navigation properties on each `PhoneNumber` and `Address` object that linked back to the Employee. I don't need them for now, so removing those navigation properties corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As an expansion on @peinearydevelopment set up your PhoneNumber:

```
    public class PhoneNumber
{
    public PhoneNumber(string name, int areaCode, string number)
    {
        Name = name;
        AreaCode = areaCode;
        Number = number;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
}
```

Set up your Employee:

```
    public class Person
{
    public Person(string first, string last, PhoneNumber home, PhoneNumber cell)
    {
        First = first;
        Last = last;
        HomeNumber = home;
        CellNumber = cell;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string First { get; set; }

    public string Last { get; set; }
    public int HomePhone_ID { get; set; }
    public int CellNumber_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual PhoneNumber HomeNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual PhoneNumber CellNumber { get; set; }
}
}
```

And your Context

```
public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, relationships are maintained, but you do need to explicitly tell your application which fields hold the identifiers, not just which tables have the relationships.